# Oracle SQL*Plus group by same id in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table some_table like

```
  id       other_id   date_value            value  
 -------- ---------- --------------------- ------- 
  1        1          2011-04-20 21:03:05   104    
  2        2          2011-04-20 21:03:04   229    
  3        3          2011-04-20 21:03:03   130    
  4        1          2011-04-20 21:02:09   97     
  5        2          2011-04-20 21:02:08   65     
  6        3          2011-04-20 21:02:07   101    
  ...      ...        ...                   ...
```

I want to create a query to group by the same id like that

```
 other_id  date_value            value  
 -------- --------------------- ------- 
  1        2011-04-20 21:03:05   104    
           2011-04-20 21:02:09   97     
  2        2011-04-20 21:03:04   229    
           2011-04-20 21:02:08   65
```

I'm a newbie...can you help me with oracle

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the repeat values in SQLPlus, use the SQLPlus [`BREAK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12009.htm#SQPUG030) command:

```
SQL> BREAK ON other_id
SQL> SELECT other_id, date_value, value FROM myTable ORDER BY other_id, date_value DESC

 other_id  date_value            value  
 -------- --------------------- ------- 
  1        2011-04-20 21:03:05      104
           2011-04-20 21:02:09       97
  2        2011-04-20 21:03:04      229
           2011-04-20 21:02:08       65
  ...      ...                   ...
```